# Mercurial Git Network view

Tags: git, mercurial, github

I really like github's "network" view, i.e. an horizontal graph of the commits, without the log informations.
It is really useful to see the commit graph in an intuitive way.

If there any tool that provides this for mercurial (and/or git)?

Comment: You could always use hg-git (or is it git-hg?) to transform your mercurial repo into a git repo, and then upload it to github. In fact, Google Code may have a tool for doing the conversion automatically. Though keeping an hg repo and a git repo in sync might be tricky, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, considering this two-year old BitBucket ticket: "[#820 Bitbucket should have something like Github's Network graph (BB-336)](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/820/bitbucket-should-have-somthing-like)".

This would have emulated the "[network graph](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer)", now [implemented using HTML5 canvas](https://github.com/blog/621-bye-bye-flash-network-graph-is-now-canvas).

[image: Canvas]

---

Note that you have a [demo](http://raphaeljs.com/github/demo.html) based on [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/), with a [collection of scripts](http://raphaeljs.com/github/) emulating the GitHub graphs (and based on Git repos, but applicable to Mercurial commits as well). Since it generates SVG, which is said to [not scale for large and complex structures](http://www.borismus.com/canvas-vs-svg-performance/), that might not be the [best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568136/svg-vs-canvas-where-is-the-web-world-going-towards).

Comment: thank you , nice lib :) but I was looking for something local, like an effective program or something installable in a local web server